# Django annotation with nested filter

Tags: django

Is it possible to filter within an annotation?

In my mind something like this (which doesn't actually work)

`Student.objects.all().annotate(Count('attendance').filter(type="Excused"))`

The resultant table would have every student with the number of excused absences. Looking through documentation filters can only be before or after the annotation which would not yield the desired results.

A workaround is this

```
for student in Student.objects.all():
    student.num_excused_absence = Attendance.objects.filter(student=student, type="Excused").count()
```

This works but does many queries, in a real application this can get impractically long. I think this type of statement is possible in SQL but would prefer to stay with ORM if possible. I even tried making two separate queries (one for all students, another to get the total) and combined them with |. The combination changed the total :(

## Some thoughts after reading answers and comments

I solved the attendance problem using extra sql [here](https://github.com/burke-software/django-sis/blob/a43cb7bfa8a99fdabdd7a783f55139b484b28d3c/ecwsp/sis/scaffold_reports.py#L118).

- [Timmy's blog post](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/filtering-annotations-django/) was useful. My answer is based off of it.
- hash1baby's answer works but seems equally complex as sql. It also requires executing sql then adding the result in a for loop. This is bad for me because I'm stacking lots of these filtering queries together. My solution builds up a big queryset with lots of filters and extra and executes it all at once.
- If performance is no issue - I suggest the for loop work around. It's by far the easiest to understand.

Comment: I've written a blog post about this as it's not possible (afaik) without either using raw SQL or simply iterating on the results: http://timmyomahony.com/blog/filtering-annotations-django/

Comment: There is a new solution for this in the ORM as of Django 1.8.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of Django 1.8 you can do this directly in the ORM:

```
students = Student.objects.all().annotate(num_excused_absences=models.Sum(
    models.Case(
        models.When(absence__type='Excused', then=1),
    default=0,
    output_field=models.IntegerField()
)))
```

Answer adapted from [another SO question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django)

I haven't tested the sample above but did accomplish something similar in my own app.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct - django does not allow you to filter the related objects being counted, without also applying the filter to the primary objects, and therefore excluding those primary objects with a no related objects after filtering.

But, in a bit of abstraction leakage, you can count groups by using a values query.

So, I collect the absences in a dictionary, and use that in a loop.  Something like this:

```
# a query for students
students = Students.objects.all()
# a query to count the student attendances, grouped by type.
attendance_counts = Attendence(student__in=students).values('student', 'type').annotate(abs=Count('pk'))
# regroup that into a dictionary {student -> { type -> count }}
from itertools import groupby
attendance_s_t = dict((s, (dict(t, c) for (s, t, c) in g)) for s, g in groupby(attendance_counts, lambda (s, t, c): s))
# then use them efficiently:
for student in students:
    student.absences = attendance_s_t.get(student.pk, {}).get('Excused', 0)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be subject to a race condition if data changes between line 2 and line 4?

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
excused = Student.objects.filter(attendance__type='Excused').annotate(abs=Count('attendance'))
```

You need to filter the Students you're looking for first to just those with excused absences and then annotate the count of them.

Here's a link to the [Django Aggregation Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) where it discusses filtering order.

Comment: The problem here is excused is now a list of students with at least one excused absence. As mentioned I thought maybe there is some way to combine this, but I haven't been able think of a way do this. The "|" can combine querysets but it effectively removes the filter thus changing the count.

Comment: guess I didn't understand the requirements right.  I was looking at "The resultant table would have every student with the number of excused absences."  Are you looking to have a results set that has one entry for each student/attendance__type combination?

Comment: Yes, like this

student | Total excused absences | Total absences | Total Tardies etc